How to animate a property of the templated control from a visualstatemanager inside a controltemplate?
I have created a custom circular progress bar control which inherits from the original WPF ProgressBar. In its default style/template I want to define a storyboard for the indeterminate animation. However, I can't seem to find a way to animate the Value property of my control. Here's the default style.
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type control:CircularProgressIndicator}" TargetType="{x:Type control:CircularProgressIndicator}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ProgressBar}}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type control:CircularProgressIndicator}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Path x:Name="PART_Path"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                              StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding StrokeThickness}">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <PathGeometry>
                                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                                        <PathFigureCollection>
                                            <PathFigure x:Name="PART_Figure">
                                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                                    <PathSegmentCollection>
                                                        <ArcSegment x:Name="PART_ArcSegment" />
                                                    </PathSegmentCollection>
                                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                                            </PathFigure>
                                        </PathFigureCollection>
                                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                                </PathGeometry>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Determinate" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!-- this throws a binding error: "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElemnt for target element." -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value"
                                                         From="0" To="100" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>

There's obviously all kinds of code in CircularProgressIndicator that manipulates the Path element based on the Value property but that shouldn't be relevant here. The problem is how generally to animate properties of the templated control itself from a storyboard. Obviously, there's no named element that I could pass to Storyboard.TargetName. I already tried some trickery with binding proxies but so far nothing worked.
I did find several entries for this problem here on SO already but they either had no answers or they solved it from outside of the template (i.e. you would either have to duplicate the relevant code at every use site or use a Behavior to encapsulate that) which IMHO defeats the purpose of having a template in the first place...
There must be some better way, mustn't there?

IMHO, utilizing Value property for intermediate animation is not a good approach. If you want to re-use the visual elememt which represents the Value, you should manipulate that visual element itself.

Animating the Value property may even raise ValueChanged events, which would be confusing for the user of your control.

OK, those are indeed valid points in this specific case and I will revise my approach. However, that still leaves the question open of how to do it in a case where that "side-effect" would be acceptable?

Have you tried RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}? And the code that manipulates Path is absolutely relevant here, cause it manipulates a property on a control, which is exactly what you are trying to do here.
